# nginx ssl subdomain error

Tags: linux, nginx, phpmyadmin, debian

Hello i have 2 problem with subdomain

- my ssl not work for sub.domain.com but work for domain.com
- phpmyadmin give me a blank page

I have already test many configuration but always i have "no input file specified" error or 502 bad getaway error or blank page

My folder is like

```
/www/
  - /website/ <- first site
  - /tools/ <- subdomain
     - phpmyadmin (symlink of /usr/share/phpmyadmin)
```

Config

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;

       ssl on;
       ssl_certificate /www/website/ssl/domain_com.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key /www/website/ssl/domain_com.key;

       ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        ssl_protocols SSLv2 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;

        disable_symlinks off;
        root /www/tools/;
        server_name configuration.domain.com;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

location /phpmyadmin {
    index index.php index.htm;
    root /usr/share;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
}
```

Im on Debian 7, Nginx 1.8

Thanks you

Comment: Anything in the error logs?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `root` based on the location you are setting, because the location will not be appended to that, so you should fix this block:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    index index.php index.htm;
    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm if you have single domain certificate, a wildcard certificate or multi domain certificate.

If you are using a single domain certificate (say abc.com) it will not work for xyz.abc.com or 123.abc.com. It will work for only abc.com

If you have procured a wildcard certificate , please check and confirm if the subdomain is a first level sub domain or second level sub domain. wildcard certificates secures only first level sub domain. So *.abc.com certificate will work for 123.abc.com, xyz.abc.com . But it will not work for 123.xyz.abc.com.

If you have procured a multi domain certificate, then check if the sub domain URL is added as SAN to the certificate.